# How to add dark lines to heat map plot

Tags: r, plot, charts, ggplot2, line

I create the following sample heat map:

```
library(reshape2) 
library(ggplot2) 
require(gridExtra)
library(RColorBrewer)
colors <- brewer.pal(9, 'Reds')
sample_data <- data.frame(matrix(sample(36, 36), nrow=6))
sample_data$id<-rownames(sample_data)
sample_data2 <- melt(sample_data, id.var="id")
ggplot(sample_data2, aes(as.factor(variable), as.factor(id), group=id)) +
    geom_tile(aes(fill = value)) + 
    geom_text(aes(fill = sample_data2$value, label = sample_data2$value), size=3) +
    scale_fill_gradientn(colours = colors) + 
    labs(x = "variable", y = "id", title="heat map")
```

This produces a plot like this:
[image]

My question is how can I add dark lines to separate selected tiles? I have  used a third-party software program to illustrate the idea in the following plot:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could define a new set of points that describe the segments you wish to draw. We use the fact that each tile is centered on the integer grid and has a width of 1.

```
my.lines<-data.frame(x=c(.5,4.5), y=c(5.5,.5), 
    xend=c(4.5,4.5), yend=c(5.5,5.5))

ggplot(sample_data2, aes(as.factor(variable), as.factor(id), group=id)) +
    geom_tile(aes(fill = value)) + 
    geom_text(aes(fill = sample_data2$value, label = sample_data2$value), size=3) +
    scale_fill_gradientn(colours = colors) + 
    labs(x = "variable", y = "id", title="heat map") + 
    geom_segment(data=my.lines, aes(x,y,xend=xend, yend=yend), size=3, inherit.aes=F)
```

[image]